# Library xml resource overlaps app resources with same id

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android app with gradle. Main app contains `main` and `debug` build variants. With different `strings.xml` files.

It worked fine intil I add library project:

```
compile project(':mylibrary')
```

This project also contains `strings.xml` and app takes strings from this library. For exmaple it takes from it `app_name`.

How to say gradle that app resources have more priority than library with same `id`?

Comment: I am afraid there is not a way. If you're add the sources as a gradle project, you have the access to the code and edit it and I'd suggest you should do so. :)

Comment: @YeLinAung the problem is that library contains ~20 strings.xml for few languages, so it looks curiously raname all matching id's